# bootstrap js transition on collapse

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I was searching for a toggle collapse button and I've been leaded to this link:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/
I've found what I was looking for, but the only problem is the transition; once I click on the button it shows my div immediately . I want it to expand slower with transition.
Here's my code:

```css
.innerdiv{
    display: block;
    width: 33%;
    padding: 50px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #2bb88d;
    margin-top: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    height: 350px;
    overflow:auto ;
    float: left;
    clear: right;
    transition: 15s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Document</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styletest.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"> more adresses </button>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
      <div class="innerdiv"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis est soluta aliquam necessitatibus quia tempora corrupti hic fuga! Perspiciatis iste vero ipsum maxime, saepe vitae dolores amet iure assumenda cum.</p></div>
      <div class="innerdiv">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit explicabo, expedita voluptate nemo commodi architecto qui libero aliquam nisi corrupti quam, dignissimos odit hic neque aperiam, repudiandae ex soluta. Iste assumenda nostrum culpa architecto fugit id laborum quidem expedita perferendis aliquam placeat distinctio, ad magni ipsam tenetur est nesciunt non pariatur esse veritatis dolores dolorem unde quos ducimus? Beatae quam, corporis hic autem quisquam quae magni totam vitae labore sapiente error ab quo animi consequuntur veniam tempore facere. Facilis, minima quo neque a quas numquam magni, laborum dignissimos accusamus ipsa facere fuga. Quam voluptate sit quas illo sequi, sed nam vero repellendus, ipsum, officia quibusdam quos consectetur voluptas dignissimos obcaecati ad non natus hic recusandae quae numquam ex. Aspernatur esse unde, expedita nisi amet laborum blanditiis accusamus corrupti ea vel! Exercitationem vel, quidem in sed dolorem ullam odit sit nisi earum nesciunt unde eaque cum labore, quam id quibusdam ab.</div>
      <div class="innerdiv">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit explicabo, expedita voluptate nemo commodi architecto qui libero aliquam nisi corrupti quam, dignissimos odit hic neque aperiam, repudiandae ex soluta. Iste assumenda nostrum culpa architecto fugit id laborum quidem expedita perferendis aliquam placeat distinctio, ad magni ipsam tenetur est nesciunt non pariatur esse veritatis dolores dolorem unde quos ducimus? Beatae quam, corporis hic autem quisquam quae magni totam vitae labore sapiente error ab quo animi consequuntur veniam tempore facere. Facilis, minima quo neque a quas numquam magni, laborum dignissimos accusamus ipsa facere fuga. Quam voluptate sit quas illo sequi, sed nam vero repellendus, ipsum, officia quibusdam quos consectetur voluptas dignissimos obcaecati ad non natus hic recusandae quae numquam ex. Aspernatur esse unde, expedita nisi amet laborum blanditiis accusamus corrupti ea vel! Exercitationem vel, quidem in sed dolorem ullam odit sit nisi earum nesciunt unde eaque cum labore, quam id quibusdam ab.</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the time of collapsing, there runs a default bootstrap class named `collapsing`. You've to override that class like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>

<style>
    .innerdiv {
        display: block;
        width: 33%;
        padding: 50px;
        margin-left: 2px;
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #2bb88d;
        margin-top: 20px;
        border-radius: 20px;
        height: 350px;
        overflow: auto;
        float: left;
        clear: right;
    }
    
    .collapsing {
        transition: 15s;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"> more adresses </button>
    <div class="collapse" id="collapseExample">
        <div class="innerdiv">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis est soluta aliquam necessitatibus quia tempora corrupti hic fuga! Perspiciatis iste vero ipsum maxime, saepe vitae dolores amet iure assumenda cum.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="innerdiv">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit explicabo, expedita voluptate nemo commodi architecto qui libero aliquam nisi corrupti quam, dignissimos odit hic neque aperiam, repudiandae ex soluta. Iste assumenda nostrum culpa
            architecto fugit id laborum quidem expedita perferendis aliquam placeat distinctio, ad magni ipsam tenetur est nesciunt non pariatur esse veritatis dolores dolorem unde quos ducimus? Beatae quam, corporis hic autem quisquam quae magni totam
            vitae labore sapiente error ab quo animi consequuntur veniam tempore facere. Facilis, minima quo neque a quas numquam magni, laborum dignissimos accusamus ipsa facere fuga. Quam voluptate sit quas illo sequi, sed nam vero repellendus, ipsum,
            officia quibusdam quos consectetur voluptas dignissimos obcaecati ad non natus hic recusandae quae numquam ex. Aspernatur esse unde, expedita nisi amet laborum blanditiis accusamus corrupti ea vel! Exercitationem vel, quidem in sed dolorem
            ullam odit sit nisi earum nesciunt unde eaque cum labore, quam id quibusdam ab.</div>
        <div class="innerdiv">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Suscipit explicabo, expedita voluptate nemo commodi architecto qui libero aliquam nisi corrupti quam, dignissimos odit hic neque aperiam, repudiandae ex soluta. Iste assumenda nostrum culpa
            architecto fugit id laborum quidem expedita perferendis aliquam placeat distinctio, ad magni ipsam tenetur est nesciunt non pariatur esse veritatis dolores dolorem unde quos ducimus? Beatae quam, corporis hic autem quisquam quae magni totam
            vitae labore sapiente error ab quo animi consequuntur veniam tempore facere. Facilis, minima quo neque a quas numquam magni, laborum dignissimos accusamus ipsa facere fuga. Quam voluptate sit quas illo sequi, sed nam vero repellendus, ipsum,
            officia quibusdam quos consectetur voluptas dignissimos obcaecati ad non natus hic recusandae quae numquam ex. Aspernatur esse unde, expedita nisi amet laborum blanditiis accusamus corrupti ea vel! Exercitationem vel, quidem in sed dolorem
            ullam odit sit nisi earum nesciunt unde eaque cum labore, quam id quibusdam ab.</div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```